# In gradle how can we replace tokens in files based on the filename

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I need to replace tokens in every file in a dir with the replacement value being the contents of a file based on the original file name, into a new dir.

e.g.

**Input:**

```
original/
|____file1.txt
|____file2.txt

replacement_contents/
|____replace_token_contents_file1.txt
|____replace_token_contents_file1.txt
```

**Desired output:**

```
output/
|____file1.txt
|____file2.txt
```

**I can do:**

```
task filter(type: Copy) {
    from 'original'
    into "output"
    expand(token: 'replace_value')
}
```

...but this replaces with a static value, not the contents of a file based on the file name of the file being copies.

Comment: Should replacement_contents have {replace_token_contents_file1.txt,replace_token_contents_file2.txt} ? I think there may be a typo in the second file. If I understood the question properly, please see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filesMatching() to separate which property file expands which source file, and you can write a task like below - (processResources extends Copy tasks ([1](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/jvm/tasks/ProcessResources.html))) . You can see some examples of how a property file should be formatted for expansion [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/gradle-beyond-the/9781449373801/ch01.html) and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html).

build.gradle

```
processResources {
    from 'original'
    into "output"
    filesMatching("**/*1.txt") {
       expand(project: replace_token_contents_file1.txt)
    }

    filesMatching("**/*2.txt") {
       expand(project: replace_token_contents_file2.txt)
    }
}
```